# "Not Enough Storage" message preventing me from using iphone 4S

Tags: iphone

I am using an iPhone 4S. This morning, the "Not Enough Storage" message popped up on my screen and refused to go away. This means that while I can open apps using siri, the message "blocks" me from using the touchscreen. So I can't even switch the phone off to reset it as I cannot slide the power bar off.

Another way to switch the phone off will be to just let the battery drain but at 85% charge, it is going to take a long time! Anyone knows how I can get rid of this message that will not go away?

Comment: Have you tried the hard reboot method suggested below? If so, did the touchscreen remain unresponsive when the iPhone rebooted?

Comment: If you press and hold the top screen sleep button - after 10 seconds you should be able to slide the device to off. Also, powering down WiFi routers and removing the SIM card if you have one might interrupt the network which can sometimes allow space to free up long enough to remove an app or two.

Answer (score 2):

Hold the home button and power button at the same time until the phone restarts. Connect it to your computer and delete some stuff :D

Answer (score 0):

Hold the home button and the lock screen button at the same time until the phone shuts down.  It will then reboot.